# Haml - Devise in Header, fields in same line

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, devise, haml

I am working with Haml, and I don't understand how one would get the email, password, and submit button to appear on the same line (which would make them all correctly in the header) of my homepage, instead they are stacked on top of each other like a normal form. Below is the code:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title
    = stylesheet_link_tag "web-app-theme/base", "web-app-theme/themes/activo/style", "web-app-theme/override"
    = csrf_meta_tag
  %body
    #container
      #header
        %h1
          %a{:href => "/"} Peer Instruction Network
        #user-navigation
          %ul.wat-cf
            %li
              .content.login
                .flash
                  - flash.each do |type, message|
                    %div{ :class => "message #{type}" }
                      %p= message
                = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => "form login" }) do |f|
                  .group.wat-cf
                    .left= f.label :email, :class => "label right"
                    .right= f.text_field :email, :class => "text_field"
                  .group.wat-cf
                    .left= f.label :password, :class => "label right"
                    .right= f.password_field :password, :class => "text_field"
                  .group.wat-cf
                    .right
                      %button.button{ :type => "submit" }
                        Login
              /= link_to "Sign In", destroy_user_session_path
      #box
        = yield
```

Answer (score 1):

`.group.wat-cf` gets translated to `<div class="group wat-cf"></div>` which is a block element.

In your CSS you should change its `display` property to `inline` or `inline-block`, in order to have them stack horizontally.

Something like:

```
.group.wat-cf {
    display: inline; /* or display: inline-block; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference whether you use HAML or raw HTML for this. The problem is, that when you use `.something`, it will create a `<div class="something">`, which is a block element.

Which means you either have to change the `display` property to `inline`, or use `float`.

```
.left, .right { float: left; }
.group { clear: both; }
```

I'd discourage from using `display: inline-block;` if you need backwards compatibility with IE, since it causes some trouble there, unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: So I leave the haml the same and change only the css?